# CSS selector for elements of specified class that are not contained in element with another class

Tags: css

I'm trying to select all elements of a given class "class1" which don't have any ancestor in "class2". I thought the following selector would work:

```
:not(.class2) .class1
```

I am putting a space between the selectors because I want all descendants of elements not in class2 to be selected.  But this didn't work, so I also tried changing the space to `>`.  However this doesn't work quite right either.

I create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9okqkhq5/1/) to demonstrate what I am expected versus what I actually see.

Update:
It seems like the issue with using "space" is that this is literally selecting every element of class1 which has *any* element in its ancestry which is not in "class2", while the problem with ">" is that it only selects elements in which the *parent* is not "class2" without regard to whether further ancestors are in that class or not.

Update 2:
After looking at the example by @DaniP it occurs to me that another way of looking at the problem is to subtract one set from another.  So I tried `.class1:not(.class2 .class1)` but this apparently does not work because `:not()` doesn't accept complex selectors.

Comment: @Paran0a Ah, I was just trying to restate the title in other words, but you bring up a good point... I wasn't really thinking of this in terms of ancestors, are you saying that is the only way it could be done?

Comment: Isn't easier just do this https://jsfiddle.net/9okqkhq5/3/ ?

Comment: `:not(.class2) .class1` selects all `.class1` which have some ancestor that doesn't match `.class2`. Not all `.class1` whose all ancestors don't match `.class2`.

Comment: @DaniP That seems to work, but could I translate that to a querySelectorAll argument?  (Yeah, I didn't mention that in my question, I didn't want to add what I thought would be an irrelevant detail at this point)

Comment: @DaniP in other words, I'm using CSS to try to prototype the selector I will need to specify which elements I am wanting to consider, but then I'm going to be using querySelectorAll to actually select them.

Comment: The way can be thinking on the opposite way ... selecting all `class1` inside `class2` instead of `class1` outside `class2` . So you will need to think again the actions for those elements .

Comment: @DaniP Well I thought maybe `.class1:not(.class2 .class1)` would work, but that doesn't highlight *anything*.